# formatted drive as ext4 in another PC. can't mount in another PC

Tags: filesystems, mount, ext4

so I have a single partition ext4 drive that I formatted in my Ubuntu desktop.

I connected it to another PC running debian and I cannot mount it.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

**some info:**

```
=> sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /media/myuser/storage/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.


root@mydesktop2:/home/myuser/scripts/system# tail /var/log/messages
Feb 24 13:30:31 mydesktop2 kernel: [ 5577.110672] EXT4-fs (sda1): bad geometry: block count 244190390 exceeds size of device (244190389 blocks)

root@mydesktop2:/home/myuser/scripts/system# fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.29.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204885504 bytes, 1953525167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x276b2fc9

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 1953525167 1953523120 931.5G 83 Linux

Command (m for help):
```

Comment: seems to be geometry issue ... maybe ubuntu is more permissive so accept building it bad ...   if you are sure you used ext4

Comment: Definitely using ext4. I used mkfs.ext4 to format it

Comment: Are you sure it is really /dev/sda in both machines?

Comment: Interesting. What does `file -s /dev/sda1` say on the machine that refuses mounting? Does fsck recognize the partition as valid ext4?

Comment: Adding to @dhag's comments, does `fsck.ext4 -nvf /dev/sda1` show anything of interest?

Comment: I'm with Rui. It seems odd that it's called /dev/sda on the Debian machine that would already have disks.

Comment: Are you using a USB enclosure or something in the new computer?  It seems to think the drive has one sector less than it should.

Comment: Oh, and check your kernel logs for any mention that the drive has an HPA.  Ubuntu may auto unlock the HPA while Debian does not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be caused by the difference in how the kernels determine the size of the partition.  If you attach the drive to the Ubuntu system again, you could use `resize2fs` to shrink the filesystem by one block so that it can be mounted on the Debian kernel:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda1 244190389
```

Comment: This answer not exactly provides an answer to the question and it should be posted in **Comments** block bellow the question.