# How exactly is ext2 upwards-compatible?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, external-hdd, ext2

I read somewhere that an operating system which knows nothing about ext3 and ext4 (i.e. antique Linux version) is able to read/write to ext4, and it detects any ext4 file system as ext2.

I am not quite sure, whether the same is possible to Tux2 to tux3 or with FAT12. (FAT64 is exFAT)

How exactly is that possible?
How exactly can **ext4 be treated like ext2?** Is there no risk for file or metadata corruption?

Comment: The ext3/4 driver will regenerate the missing data when the filesystem is mounted.

Comment: It would mount ext4 with ext2 subsystem

Comment: Thanks. I just wondered how a clueless antique OS with only _ext2_ can make use of ***ext4.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends heavily on how the ext4 filesystem was formatted.  Some newer ext4 features (e.g. `extents` or `64bit`) cannot be understood by older ext2 drivers, and the kernel would refuse to mount the filesystem (see, for example [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426288/formatted-drive-as-ext4-in-another-pc-cant-mount-in-another-pc)).  In general, any filesystem formatted with a modern `mke2fs` with the default `-t ext4` options will **not** be mountable by an old ext2 driver, but if the filesystem was originally formatted a long time ago, then upgraded to ext4, it *may* still be mountable by ext2 if none of the newer ext4-specific features were enabled.

The ext2/3/4 filesystems track which features are in use by `compat`, `rocompat`, and `incompat` feature flags.  These features are normally set at `mke2fs` time, but can sometimes be changed by `tune2fs`.  If an unknown `compat` feature is found, the kernel will mount it, but `e2fsck` will refuse to check it because it might do something wrong.  If an unknown `rocompat` feature is found, the kernel can mount the filesystem read-only, and any unknown `incompat` feature will prevent the filesystem from being mounted at all (a message will be printed to `/var/log/messages` in this case).

You can use `debugfs -c -R features <device>` to dump the features enabled on a filesystem, for example:

```
# debugfs -c -R features /dev/sdb1
debugfs 1.42.13.wc5 (15-Apr-2016)
/dev/sdb1: catastrophic mode - not reading inode or group bitmaps
Filesystem features: has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype
needs_recovery dirdata sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink
```

Though this doesn't tell you which ones are `compat`, `rocompat`, or `incompat`.  If your version of `debugfs` doesn't understand some newer feature, it will print it like `I0400` or similar.

Comment: Yea, in general, older systems can read-only mount ext3 since it is safe to ignore the journal for read-only access, but not ext4, since several of the features that make it ext4 are incompat.